# How to retrieve a HTML element in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use asp.net and C# 4.

I would like to know if is possible and how to retrieve a "Normal" (not asp.net) element in Code Behind.

For instance: I have a `<li></li>`, I would like get it from my logic and set is Visible to False.

At the moment I tried to change the MarkUp with:

```
    <li ID="li-item" runat="server">
    // Does not work I get Error: ID no identified....
```

I'm pretty new to Asp.Net, please give me a sample of code. Thanks for your support.
PS: I hope to do not get down votes because it is a too trivial question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"li-item"` is not a valid identifier. And you need to close the `li` tag.

Try:

```
<li ID="li_item" runat="server"></li>
```

(I have used an underscore instead of `-`)

Now it should work

Comment: @Porco happened to me many times, and I keep forgetting too ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it has an id and runat=server then you should be able to access it as a HtmlGenericControl, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul runat="server" id="ULSlider" class="slider_bg_container">
       <%-- <li>
            <img src="images/Home_Main.jpg" alt="" width="704" height="312" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slde1.jpg" alt="" width="704" height="312" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slde2.jpg" alt="" width="704" height="312" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slde3.jpg" alt="" width="704" height="312" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/Slde4.jpg" alt="" width="704" height="312" />
        </li>--%>
    </ul>
```

and in code i use this like

```
protected void LoadData()
    {
        ImageGalleryBAL objImageBAl = new ImageGalleryBAL();
        DataSet ds=objImageBAl.ImageGallery_GetALLImageForSlider();
        String s="";
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string imgUrl =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteURL"]+ dr["ImageName"].ToString();
            string AltText = dr["AltText"].ToString();
            s=s+"<li><img src='"+imgUrl+"' alt='"+AltText+"' width='704' height='312' /> </li>";
        }
        ULSlider.InnerHtml = s;

    }
```